# Getting the range of a cell a function is launched from

Tags: google-sheets

I have got a dictionary from an URLfetch. What I want to do is write the values in the row the script is launched from, but I don't know how to navigate trough the cells.

So how to get the range of the cell a function is launched from?

Thanks

```js
function separate(Json) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("JsonData");
  // cell = range of the cell the function is launched from
  sheet.getRange(x).setValue(0."currentvalue")
  // where x is the value on the b columns of the same row
  sheet.getRange(y).setValue(0."marketcap")
  // where y is the value on the c columns of the same row
  // repeating this for every value of the dictionary that I want in my sheet. 


  return Json.O."id" // write the id in the cell in which the function is launched from
}
```

[Here is how I want to call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYmew.png)

[Dictionary in a list taken into argument as Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5KEZ.png)

Comment: Hi there @EdouardD.! Unfortunately I don't understand «*I wanna do is write the values in the row the script is launched from*», could you please clarify it? It would be really helpful if you could show an example of the desired result. Also please share your current script/formula.

Comment: Hi, @Jacques-GuzelHeron ! I just modified my post and added more information

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the data being written vertically right now. If your goal is to write it horizontally, then you can use [`TRANSPOSE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) around your function to transmute your column into a row-

## UPDATE

The solution above will work in a formula based approach. If you want to use an Apps Script approach, you could do the following. First you have to familiarize yourself with [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). The first method will read values from a given range. In this scenario it should be used to load the dictionary values into Apps Script and save them into an array. At this point you have an array with the dictionary values stored in a column-life fashion, but since you want them in a row-like fashion you should transpose the array. To do it easily you can use the function at the bottom. Now you can safely take your row-like array and paste it into the Sheet with `Range.setValues()`. Please write back with any doubt about this second answer.

```js
function transposeArray(array) {
  return array[0].map((col, i) => array.map(row => row[i]));
}
```